# MVC, where store current state object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC web application I have to store a huge anount information in a memory during one session, such a kind of business layer.  Is it any other, more efficient way to store it, except to store it in a session variable, like this:

```
Session["MyData"] = new myGiantStructure();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "more efficient"? You say you need it in memory and it doesn't look like there's any processing involved.

Comment: My first question would be, why do you need to store so much session data. in memory is the quickest way to access it.

Comment: Memory cache? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1